# OnClickListener isn't working for ImageView

Tags: java, android

I'm pretty sure everything is right but the log isn't showing up in the console area of Eclipse when I click any of the images.

Ultimately, I want to have a popup menu appear when these images are clicked but right now I'm just trying to get the onclick events working correctly and then I'll add those in later.

My code:

Java

```
public class SecondScreen extends HelloAndroid {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.main2);

           // initialize header
           ImageView header = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.header_image);
           header.setOnClickListener(headerClick);

           // Make sure vitals and details are same size
           LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
           params.weight = 0.5f;

           // initialize vitals image
           ImageView vitals = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.vitalsigns_image);
           vitals.setLayoutParams(params);
           vitals.setOnClickListener(vitalsClick);

           // initialize details image
           ImageView details = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.details_image);
           details.setLayoutParams(params);
           details.setOnClickListener(detailsClick);




       }

        private OnClickListener headerClick = new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.d("Clicked", "Header Clicked!");



            }
       };


        private OnClickListener vitalsClick = new OnClickListener() {

             public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.d("Clicked", "Vitals Clicked!");



             }
        };

        private OnClickListener detailsClick = new OnClickListener() {

             public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.d("Clicked", "Details Click!");



             }
        };
}
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <!-- HEADER -->

    <ImageView 
       android:id="@+id/header_image"
       android:src="@drawable/header"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    /> 



<!-- FOOTER -->
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#000000"  
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
    >


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/vitalsigns_image"
        android:src="@drawable/vitalsigns"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/details_image"
        android:src="@drawable/details"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: why soo much white space in your code.. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may need to make your ImageView clickable, either using `setClickable(true)` or `android:clickable="true"` in XML

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setClickable(boolean)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply but after adding that to all of my ImageViews, the log is still not showing up in my Console tab in Eclipse. Any other ideas?

Comment: and you're seeing other logging ok in general?

Comment: I guess not. I tried another example online got the clicks to register but still not logging. It seems like a problem with my Eclipse setup. Know any fixes?

Comment: Maybe this is my problem. It's saying that I have too many devices connected when I run adb logcat. All I have is my phone connected via usb and no emulator running. "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools>adb logcat
- waiting for device -
error: more than one device and emulator
- waiting for device -
error: more than one device and emulator
- waiting for device -
error: protocol fault (status read)
- waiting for device -
error: protocol fault (status read)"

Comment: whenever I get an error like that I am usually able to clear it with `adb kill-server` and then `adb start-server`

Comment: Eh, unfortunately that didn't do anything for me. Still getting the same error.

Comment: (looks like the system wants to move this discussion to chat, which is fine with me, but it's your post)... do you have a physical device and an emulator going? or just an emulator?

Answer (score 5):

I faced the same problem. After struggling for hours, was able to figure out a solution by myself. If the ImageView is inside RelativeLayout or LinearLayout, just add `android:focusable="true"`. The ImageView also should have `android:focusable="true"` and `android:clickable="true"`

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and fixed in by adding `android:layout_width="44dp"` to make sure **user would have enough area to click on**. Then, you can align image content the way you wannt. In my case:

```
    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/locationImageView"
    android:layout_width="44dp"
    android:layout_height="16dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@id/locationText"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitStart"
    android:src="@drawable/icn_edit_small_white"/>
```